# Junit Test objectMapper readValue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, mockito

can someone please help me?

I want't to test objectMapper.readValue() - when i send invalid string throw JsonProcessingException exception.

Method test :

```
@GetMapping("/find-example")
    public Sort<Example> findByExample(@RequestParam String example) throws IOException {
        Example exampleObject = objectMapper.readValue(example, Example.class);
        return exampleService.findByExample(exampleObject);
    }
```

I'm stuck for a week now with this test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do that is having a real ObjectMapper being injected in the Controller while testing it.

Nevertheless, in my opinion, that is something you should avoid. You are basically testing code that is not yours.

Comment: I tried first option and it doesnt works.  Its throwing me JsonProcesigException N/A

Comment: Then can you please add your test code to the question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68875103/junit-test-jsonprocessingexception/68883818#68883818 there is the code, can you please explain me what should i do?

Comment: But then you are not testing `objectMapper.readValue()` since you are mocking it. Use a real ObjectMapper instead: `private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();`.

Comment: It should, but you can even remove `final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()` and just keep it at a test class level instead of `@MockBean private ObjectMapper objectMapper;`.

Comment: Is this ok now?    assertThrows(JsonParseException.class, ()->{ final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); objectMapper.readValue(queryParams, Example.class); });

Comment: I need MockBean ObjectMapper for different test so I can't remove it. 
Thank you so much.

Comment: Then it should as you showed in your previous comment.